# Replacing two fence posts within a 32" span

Tags: concrete, fence

I had to dig out two badly rotted fence posts with cracked concrete. These are roughly 2' deep to accommodate a 4' post. These are so close that I'm really wondering what to do about this middle section.

Would you:

1. Set the posts, leaving the dirt that’s between, and filling over top and connecting with concrete
2. Dig out the dirt between and fill the whole thing with concrete, setting the posts with a single concrete pour
3. Fill the whole thing with dirt, tamp it down, and then dig two new clean holes, filling each with concrete
4. None of those, ya goober!

[image: Post holes]

Comment: 5. any of the above ... why are there two posts so close together?

Comment: @jsotola Ah! Clever, how about 6. All at the same time, just mix the dirt with the concrete. 

Comment: 1. would be the simplest

Comment: 7A (or 4) with that type of fence, use galvanized steel posts as per usual. Won't rot, take a long time to rust. 7B (or 4) With wooden posts, skip the concrete that just helps the post rot faster, fill with well-tamped dirt (tamp every couple of inches of backfilling) and use **ground-contact** treated posts.

Comment: I think Aaron is joking but just in case do not mix dirt with concrete , the advantage to concrete a wider top is normal this provides more stability but Ecnerwal is correct tamped posts are usually fine for a fence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going with the first option since it was indeed the easiest, and when these need to be replaced, it'll be easier to break up than an entirely solid footing.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to close out the question.